# Repeat header row after each row dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I repeat the header row after each row of gridview?

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might add code to the rowdatabound-event of your grid:

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Header" }); //as needed

        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        Table tbl = (e.Row.Parent as Table);

        tbl.Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex * 2 + 1, row);            
    }
}
```

In this example, I have removed the gridview header altogether as you write your own in code behind.

Comment: Hi, Jan-Frederik Carl it is good code, but if i want to display the header for every 10 rows then how can i write the code.

Comment: In the method, you should check the RowIndex-property if it is dividable by 10 without rest. In that case, add the header after the row. Have no time to put the code together at the moment, but can do it later if still needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't without re-writing the control render method. How about using a repeater and putting it in the item separator element too?

Comment: can u please tell me how to do it in render method

Comment: It'd probably be best describing your scenario as overriding the render is no other option approach and usually quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is way easier to either put the markup for the header also in the item template. Overriding the Render method for something like this is probably overkill.

But if there is a reason to do this, it is at least missing from your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the header row markup in *every single* item row, why not just include the markup that is currently in your header into the ItemTemplate ...?