# How to repeat the header template in gridview?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net, I am using gridview for displaying the data. In gridview I am displaying 300 records at a time. Now I want to display the header template after every 30 rows in gridview is it possible?
I write like this in gridview_rowdatabound.

```
     GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);  
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Header" }); //as needed
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Name" }); //as needed
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "add" }); //as needed
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Nice" }); //as needed
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        Table tbl = (e.Row.Parent as Table); 
        tbl.Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex * 3 + 1, row);
```

when I place  tbl.Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex * 2 + 1, row);   it is working when I place more than 2 like 3, 4 like this, then it is throing error.

I solve the problem:

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
       {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            ViewState["i"] = e.Row.RowIndex;
        }

        if (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["i"].ToString()) == e.Row.RowIndex)
        {
            GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BurlyWood;
            cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "header" }); //as needed              
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BurlyWood;
            cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Name" }); //as needed
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BurlyWood;
            cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "add" }); //as needed
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BurlyWood;
            cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Nice" }); //as needed
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            int cnt = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["i"].ToString());

            Table tbl = (e.Row.Parent as Table);

            //tbl.Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex * cnt , row);
             tbl.Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex, row);               

            cnt = cnt + 4;
            ViewState["i"] = cnt.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i take the e.row.rowindex in integr varaible and check the condition when  if(e.row.rowindex== i) then display the header and in if condition i assign the value to i like i=i+30, before that i write a condition for assing the value for, please check i am updating my question in that i am placing the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

1. Remove your header of your gridview from your aspx page
2. Now write the RowDataBound method

   ```
   protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

           TableCell cell = new TableCell();
           cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Header" }); //as needed

           row.Cells.Add(cell);

           Table tbl = (e.Row.Parent as Table);

           tbl.Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex * 29 + 1, row);            
       }
   }
   ```

[Repeat Header row after few rows dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140569/repeat-header-row-after-each-row-dynamically)

Comment: Mr. Anadnd infact it is throwing error like: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Please add the required here like cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "Name" });cell.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "LastName" });

Answer (score 0):

Would you please check it out:[GridView Examples for Paging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx), thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses the actual header of the GridView and therefore does not rely on manually adding a label for each column:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowIndex + 1) % 30 == 0)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

            for(int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (gv.Columns[i].Visible)
                {
                    TableCell objTC = new TableCell();
                    objTC.Font.Bold = true;
                    objTC.Text = gv.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                    row.Cells.Add(objTC);
                }
            }

        Table tbl = (e.Row.Parent as Table);

        // add row above the current row so that sequencing isn't affected
        tbl.Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex - 1, row);
    }
}
```